# Adjusting the div margin with Bootstrap responsive mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following row in my html and I developed it using the bootstrap responsive CSS. I would like to push the SPAN4 -15px in Desktop and Tablets.

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="lat1">
   <div class="span8></div>
   <div class="span4></div>
</div>
```

I tried the following solution and its not working. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
@media (min-width: 320px){
    #lat1 .span4 {
        margin-left : -15px;
    }
}
```

Also, Are the media queries supported in all browsers that support HTML5?

Comment: Have you tried `@media screen and (...` ? Note - your missing the ending quotes. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5F7Q/)

Comment: I just made the changes from your CSS and it works fine in Chrome but not in FF. I tried cleaning the cache also. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think adding "screen" will make any difference, bootstrap CSS doesn't use it, just make sure you're adding your CSS file after boostrap's. Also bootstrap uses 768px as the breakpoint for its grid system so you might want to set that as yours too.

Comment: This does not look as a good approach. Why change the bootstrap responsive grid this way? What do you want to do exactly? For media-queries browser compatibility check here: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Comment: I am porting an existing HTML4 site to produce similar look using bootstrap. I have an image in span8 and text links in san4. image is a fixed size image and not visible on phones. On larger screens, there is a gap between the span8 and span4 and I want to reduce it until I come up with the proper image. I agree that -15px is not a good approach. I need a temp solution until i get all contributors to upload proper images. Thanks.